# Find all nodes within a subtree that has 0 or 1 children

Tags: mysql, sql

In something I need to work on, at a given time, I need to find all nodes of a tree (made using the materialized path + adjacent nodes) that have 0 or 1 children.
The columns are something like:

```
id int  
parent_node int  
treepath VARCHAR(255)  
deepness int
```

When I try to come up with a solution to this, I'm only able to think of very complex queries that would use too many subqueries or table joins.

For the nodes with 0 children, I've been thinking of searching for all nodes that are not referenced by a parent_id and are within a subtree.

```
SELECT *
FROM user_tree
WHERE
    node_id NOT IN (
        SELECT parent_id
        FROM user_tree
        WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
    )
    AND
    treepath LIKE 
        (
            SELECT CONCAT(treepath, '/%')
            FROM user_tree
            WHERE node_id = 4
        )
```

Using the EXPLAIN, this seems to be kinda painful for the DB in therms of how long it takes to get the node list.

Is there a non-very-painful way (in performance) to make a query that finds what I want?

EDIT:
As requested, here's some sample format of the table:

```
id      parent_id   treepath    deepness
1       NULL        1           0
2       NULL        2           0
3       1           1/3         1
4       1           1/4         1
5       4           1/4/5       2
7       3           1/3/7       2
8       3           1/3/8       2
9       7           1/3/7/11    3
```

Comment: Since you're using `CONCAT`, some sample data would be nice, so that we can take a look on how your data is structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without sample data, this is just a guess:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.numchildren
FROM user_tree t1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT parent_id, COUNT(*) AS numchildren
            FROM user_tree
            GROUP BY parent_id ) t2
ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
WHERE t2.numchildren IS NULL
OR t2.numchildren = 1;
```

[SQL-Fiddle from sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1dcea/1/0)

Comment: Done. Added some sample

Comment: This is the one that worked best with me in both speed and simplicity

Answer (score 1):

Query

```
SELECT parent_id, COUNT(id) AS n FROM user_tree GROUP BY parent_id HAVING n = 1
```

finds parents having one child. You may want to add INDEX(parent_id).

Query

```
SELECT id FROM user_tree WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM user_tree)
```

finds leaves. The same index will help.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your query is correct.  I would move the conditions to the `from` clause, because that often optimizes better:

```
SELECT ut.*
FROM user_tree ut join
     (select CONCAT(treepath, '/%') as treepath4
      FROM user_tree
      WHERE node_id = 4
     ) node4 
     on ut.treepath LIKE node4.treepath4 left outer join
     user_tree child
     on child.parent_id = ut.node_id
WHERE ut.treepath LIKE node4.treepath4 and
      child.node_id is null;
```

For 0 or 1 children:

```
SELECT ut.*
FROM user_tree ut join
     (select CONCAT(treepath, '/%') as treepath4
      FROM user_tree
      WHERE node_id = 4
     ) node4
     on ut.treepath LIKE node4.treepath4 left outer join
     user_tree child
     on child.parent_id = ut.node_id
GROUP BY ut.node_id
HAVING count(child.node_id) in (0, 1);
```

Comment: Done. Added some sample

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can add new field `children_count` to the table. This will massively optimize this particular query. But you'll lose some time on add/remove nodes.

Comment: Not a good idea. It would slow many queries down for too much.

Comment: Yeah, I noted that. That all depends on the particular problem.